# How can I extract a submatrix in scilab

Tags: matrix, scilab

I have a 4×4 matrix A =

```
4   3   2   1
3   2   1   0
0   1   2   3
2   1   0   -1
```

I want to extract the 2nd, 3rd and 4th row with the 1st, 2nd and 4th column, skipping the 3rd column.

I have tried `A(2:4,1:4)`, but it also extracts the 3rd column which I don't want.
So I did this

```
submatrix = A(2:4,1:4)
submatrix(:,3) = []
```

It works fine.
But is there a way I could do it with one instruction?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
submatrix = A(2:4,[1 2 4])
```

Comment: Great. Can you validate the answer then ?